# Should I store telephone numbers as strings or integers?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to decide between storing a phone number as a `string` or an `int`. Any ideas?

Comment: Answer updated, wanted to write `string` only.

Comment: An `Int32` (`int`) handles up to ~2 1/4 billion. Telephone numbers (with area codes) can be up to 9,999,999,999 (10 billion if you include (000)-000-0000). Also, this failure is already _on_ [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Confessions-The-Phone-Number.aspx). I expect this question _and_ this comment get _very_ popular so everyone can see this.

Comment: @ColeJohnson - I was just going to comment about that - I recall seeing a story (I think) on the Daily WTF about a situation where the phone number was being stored as Int32, and the max value (2147483647) actually corresponded to a live phone number (or something along those lines).

Comment: @Tim that's actually what I was looking for after commenting! :D Updated with link (Google `phone number site:thedailywtf.com`). Also, that phone number is still active I believe. Poor souls.

Comment: @ColeJohnson - Thanks for finding (and posting) the link. :)

Comment: Closing a C# question as a duplicate of a Java question.  Hmmm....

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For any situation like these, think of : will I have to calculate anything with that value? If that doesn't make any sense, you should use a string. In that case, there's no logical case where you'd use the telephone number as a number, so use a string.

Comment: +1 for the rule of thumb.

Comment: This may sound dumb but isn't the phone number a number? There is uint64 so I actually see no reason to use a string unless you don't want to validate it(which can only be a bad practice).

Comment: In fact, it's more of a code represented by a sequence of digits. But it's surely not treated as a number. It doesn't make sense to do arithmetic operations on a phone number. What about a number starting with zeros? In France, phone numbers are in forms of 0x xx xx xx xx, using uint64 would mean you lose the leading zero.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using a string since that gives you more flexibility when it comes to formatting and non numeric characters like extension etc.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using `String` - aside from anything else, otherwise you won't be able to store leading zeroes. You *definitely* shouldn't use `int` (too small) `float` or `double` (too much risk of data loss); `long` or `BigInteger` could be appropriate (aside from the leading zeroes problem), but frankly I'd go with `String`. That way you can *also* store whatever dashes or spaces the user has entered to make it easier to remember the number, if you want to.

Reference: [What's the right way to represent phone numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483156/whats-the-right-way-to-represent-phone-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend you use a `string` for this.

If you are going to validate phone number input then you can use the regex lib's `matcher` and `pattern` to make sure a phone number was entered in the correct format.