# Change the value of the fields of an object, that are int, with java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have a table with 3 fields, name = varchar, number1 = int, number2 = int

Below I can modify a single field at a time. 
How could I change all fields of type int for a single time?

```
public static void change(Object t) throws IllegalArgumentException,
IllegalAccessException {
    Class c = t.getClass(); 
    Field f = t.getDeclaredFields()[0];
    f.set(o, "name2");
    int a = f.getModifiers();
    System.out.println(Modifier.isVolatile(a));
    Field f2 = t.getDeclaredFields()[1];
    f2.setInt(t, 10);
    int a2 = f2.getModifiers();
    System.out.println(Modifier.isVolatile(a2));
}
```

The step that I like to follow is to check whether the field is int, and then assign the value 10 fixed them all. Whit java reflect.

to get the second and third field automatically,

I try this

```
public static void sta(Object t) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
Class<?> c = t.getClass();
for (Field f : t.getDeclaredFields()) {
    if (f.getType() == int.class) {
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(t, 10);
    }
}


test.java

public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
    Object t = new Object("Name1", 777, 777);


    teste2.sta(t);
System.out.println(t.number1);

}}

Object.java

public class Object {
String name;
int number1;
    int number2;
public Object(String name, int number1, int number2){
    this.name=name;
    this.numeber1=number1;
            this.number2=number2 ;
}
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public int getNumber1(){
    return number1;
}
public int getNumber2(){
    return number2;
    }
}
```

the error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field Object.name to java.lang.Integer
    at  un.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)   at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741)
    at teste2.sta(teste2.java:76)
    at teste2.main(teste2.java:95)
Java Result: 1
```

how do I get the output of System.out.println (t.number1); be modified value by the method teste2.sta (t);

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
        Object t = new Object("Name1", 777, 777);


        teste2.sta(t);
    System.out.println(t.number1);

    }}
```

Comment: t.getDeclaredFields()[0];

accesses the first field, so what about iterating all fields?

Comment: What't the type of t in the case of the exception?

Comment: Phone numbers are not ints. Store phone numbers [**as strings**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483156/whats-the-right-way-to-represent-phone-numbers), never as ints.

Comment: I added the code and builders, look at the question again please. if phone number is not int and string. As this is only an example.

Comment: @Alopex There are many basic compilation errors in your code. It cannot possibly throw the exception you claim it does, because it does not compile at all. However, once those basic errors are fixed, it runs without throwing any exception. It doesn't do anything else though, because you don't have any fields of type `int`.

Comment: And how can I fix it?

Comment: @Alopex You don't. There's nothing wrong with it, except that it doesn't do anything. But that's because you haven't given it anything to do. You asked how to change int fields -- you haven't got any.

Comment: System.out.println(t.number2); in test.java does not return the modified value by reflection. teste2.sta(t);

Comment: @Alopex **You asked how to change `int` fields. `number2` isn't an `int`.**

Comment: Thanks, sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code iterates over all int fields declared directly in the concrete class of a given object obj, and sets them all to 10:

```
Class<?> c = obj.getClass();
for (Field f : c.getDeclaredFields()) {
    if (f.getType() == int.class) {
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(obj, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: f.set (a, 10); rather than f.set (obj, 10);

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field Object.name to java.lang.Integer

Comment: @Alopex: Thanks, fixed the typo. Can you please provide more details about the IllegalArgumentException? for what input does it happen?

Comment: @Alopex: I would like to reproduce the exception. What value do you use for t?

Comment: @Alopex Eyal's code is good. I don't see how it could possibly throw that exception.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I will test on another machine.