# take members selected by concrete digits

Tags: c#, linq

I want to select specific members whose phones start with "02".
I have class Student with this
constructor

```
public Student(string firstName, string lastName, int fn, int tel, string email, List<int> allMarks, int groupNumber)
```

Make a `List<Student> students`.

And that I want to do is to select this members that their telephone start with '02' (for my example)

I try this:

1st

```
var tel = students.Where(x => x.Tel.ToString().StartsWith("02")).ToArray();
Print(tel);
```

2nd

```
var testTel = students
.Select(x => x.Tel.ToString().Substring(0, 2) == "02")
.Select(x => x);
Print(testTel);
```

3rd

```
var someTel =
    from t in students
    where t.Tel.ToString().Substring(0, 2).Equals("02")
    select t.Tel;
```

And some more... but on the end I make (convert /int Tel to string Tel/) and work.

I want to ask is there a way to select this member when `int Tel` part of list:

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>() 
    {
        new Student("Nataly", "Adams", 8222, 029669, "hot@mail.com", 
                new List<int>{2, 3, 3, 5, 6}, 2),
        new Student("Ben", "Dueyn", 8215, 0886996321, "hot@mail.com", 
                new List<int>{4, 5, 4, 5, 5}, 2),
    };
```

Comment: no, because "int 00123" equals "int 123"

Comment: When you're storing the phone number as an `int`, you're losing your leading `0`. You should store them as `String`.

Comment: Making Tel as integer is a conceptual error. You cannot add or substract tel numbers ... It should be string by definition. Byt the way, for your problem, you need a ToString to using string comparison ...

Comment: Best way to store phone numbers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483156/whats-the-right-way-to-represent-phone-numbers

Comment: Thanks for advice. I am very grateful.
Sorry for bad structure of the question and ...for the language

Answer (score 2):

Set your `tel` property as string, then you can simply use lambda expression like this:

```
var tel = students.Where(x => x.Tel.StartsWith("02")).ToList<Student>();
```

The answer why you should use string with telephone's number, you can find here - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483156/whats-the-right-way-to-represent-phone-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

The most important bits and pieces are already said in the comments to your question. To iterate again:

- 02 equals 2 when it comes to an Int32 value.
- if you convert an int value with a leading 0 to a string, the leading zero gets lost.

The easisest way to get what you want, is to change your student class, so the phone number is of type `String`. As is Jon Skeets linked answer, this also enables you to store every possible special character like dashes, hyphens, parenthesis etc.

So change your class to this:

```
public class Student
{
    public Student(string fname, string lname, int fn, string tel, string mail, List<int> marks, int groupNumber)
    {
        this.firstName = fname;
        this.lastName = lname;
        this.fn = fn;
        this.tel = tel;
        //...
    }
    //...
    public string tel { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

And you can easily get what you want by using:

```
var result = students.Where(x => x.tel.StartsWith("02"));
```