# SQL Query to concat a string in the database

Tags: mysql

I have a database table, with a column that contains integers. Each entry is a phone number, and they are all missing a zero at the beginning.

e.g. I have 798514586,
            785558999

I want to run a SQL query that will modify each entry by putting a zero infront of it.

So the result will be
           0798514586,
           0785558999

IS there such a query to do this?

Comment: Storing a phone number as Integer is not a good idea, store it as a string and concate zero.

Comment: What's the downside to storing phone numbers as integers?

Comment: Look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483156/whats-the-right-way-to-represent-phone-numbers he explained it very well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Syntax:

```
UPDATE <table> SET <column_to_update> = CONCAT(<string_to_concat>, <column_to_update>)
```

Example:

```
UPDATE contacts SET phone = CONCAT('0', phone)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you dont't want to add leading zero if it already exists:

```
update TableName
set SomeColumn = concat('0', SomeColumn)
where SomeColumn not like '0%'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to store phone numbers as INTs, it's better to use a VARCHAR here. I would suggest you do add a new varchar column:

```
ALTER TABLE numbers ADD COLUMN phone_new VARCHAR(15);
```

then you can use an UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE numbers
SET
  phone_new = CONCAT('0', phone)
```

MySQL will automatically cast the number to a string, and using CONCAT you can add a leading zero.

Comment: What would be the advantage of using varchar over text?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by this:

```
update tableName set fieldName = CONCAT('0',fieldName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LPAD :

```
Update _table set _col  = LPAD(_col , 10, '0');
```