# I want to convert a telephone number into specific format if it is not in that format

Tags: php

I have a telephone number and its type is **varchar(32)**. It could be **03004748495**,**3004748495**, **0300-4748495**, **300-4748495**,**+92-300-4748495** or **923004748495**. I want it to be converted in this format **923004748495** as an integer if it is not in this format. How will I achieve that? Any ideas?

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: I had tried different things but they were not generic. i want a generic function to handle all these problems. I mean if I had `-` in the telephone, I used explode.. But that was just for one case. Not generic.

Comment: Is the country code 92? And is it implied in cases where it is not present like "03..." means "923...";  "3...." means "923..." etc. ?

Comment: You shouldn't use an integer for phone numbers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483156/whats-the-right-way-to-represent-phone-numbers

Comment: Yes 92 is the country code. And 0300 is the carrier code.

Comment: @Ivar Actually my telephone type is varchar, but in order to send sms, the format has to be 92xxxxxxxxxx. Without any + or - in between. So im converting telephone number into that format.

Comment: Alright. That makes sense. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_replace` to remove unwanted signs (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```
<?php

$number = '+92-300-4748495';

$number = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $number);

echo $number;
```

If you want to remove the leading zero too, you could use `rtrim` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php)

```
<?php

$number = '0300-4748495';

$number = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $number);

$number = ltrim($number, '0');

echo $number;
```

Additional request "If 92 is not added at the start, Add 92 also."

```
<?php
$number = '123456';

if (substr($number, 0, 2) != '92') {
    $number = '92' . $number;
}

echo $number;
```

Comment: If 92 is not added at the start, Add 92 also.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using [liphonenumber-for-php](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php)

Example code from the github page:

```
$swissNumberStr = "044 668 18 00";

// First call the class
$phoneUtil = \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();
try {

    // turn it into a object using a given geo code
    $swissNumberProto = $phoneUtil->parse($swissNumberStr, "CH"); 

    // validate the phonenumber
    $isValid = $phoneUtil->isValidNumber($swissNumberProto);

    if($isValid){

        // Produces "+41446681800"
        echo $result_number = $phoneUtil->format($swissNumberProto, \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberFormat::E164);
         // Produces "044 668 18 00"
        echo $result_number = $phoneUtil->format($swissNumberProto, \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberFormat::NATIONAL);
        // Produces "+41 44 668 18 00"
        echo $result_number = $phoneUtil->format($swissNumberProto, \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberFormat::INTERNATIONAL);
    }

} catch (\libphonenumber\NumberParseException $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```