# How can I convert nullable datetime to decimal in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, decimal

I am trying to convert a `DateTime?` value to `Decimal`. (Note: that `DateTime?` is `Nullable`)

From this format `4/1/2011 12:00:00 AM` to this format (of `Decimal` type) `20110401`.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: are you sure you want a `decimal` and not a `string`? A string representation in your format can be created via `ToString`: `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMdd")`

Comment: Yes it needs to be decimal

Comment: Then just after doing the `ToSting("yyyyMMdd")` convert to decimal

Comment: `dateTime.Year * 10000 + dateTime.Month * 100 + dateTime.Day`.

Comment: but datetime value does not convert ToSring()

Comment: Sure it does.  Practically everything (are there any exceptions?) supports ToString().  This compiles and runs fine:

DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now;
string zNow = dtNow.ToString();

Comment: _Why_ does it need to be a decimal? Sounds like an X-Y problem.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
DateTime? myDateTime = GetDateTime();
Decimal.Parse(myDateTime.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

or:

```
DateTime myDateTime = GetDateTime();
Decimal.Parse(myDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

Depending on if `DateTime` is `Nullable` or not.

But you really should consider storing it in some other fashion than `Decimal` it would be like storing a phone number as a `Long`, [which you really shouldn't do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483156/whats-the-right-way-to-represent-phone-numbers?noredirect=1&lq=1). Mainly because mathematical operations don't make sense when performed on an object stored this way.

Comment: mydatetime is not string so it gives error when I use ToString("yyyyMMdd")

Comment: @Nakres - What error does it tell you? A DateTime does not need to be a string to call `ToString(...)`.

Comment: @Nakres what Type is your actual date time stored as originally? The actual `DateTime` type contains the `.ToString` method (basically, show us your code).

Comment: The data is coming from USSI. after servicess in my code i can see it like that 4/1/2015 12:00:00 AM

Comment: Yes, @Nakres but what `Type` is it: `String`, `Char[]`, `DateTime`..?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this,,

```
DateTime? dateTime = DateTime.Today;
string dateStr = dateTime.ToString("MMddyyyy");
decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(dateStr);
```

Comment: I am gonna loose my mind. how can i use tostring for datetime. does code really work in your machine?

Comment: ToString method locates inside the base class of all classes, so it exists in any class you create!

Comment: Except, that is a nullable DateTime so do `dateTime.Value.ToString("MMddyyyy")`

Comment: @Crowcoder  Sometimes he calls it DateTime and sometimes DateTime?.  Good catch!

Comment: @Crowcoder, why do you need `dateTime.Value.ToString()`? `DateTime.ToString()` works fine for me?

Comment: type was datetime? and dateTime.Value.ToString("MMddyyyy") worked:)

Comment: @JamesHughes, the nullable DateTime won't accept a format string.

Comment: @Crowcoder, ahh, didn't see the `?` in this code, nothing to suggest the OP is using nullable though, but it might explain why he doesn't seem to be able to get the obvious option to work

Comment: @JamesHughes, yeah, my comment was more about why this specific answer wasn't working for OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a little math:

```
DateTime? dt = DateTime.Today;
decimal d = dt.Value.Year*10000 + dt.Value.Month*100 + dt.Value.Day
```

...or convert it:

```
DateTime? dt = DateTime.Today;
decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

In case, you try to use this decimal value for sorting purposes, please consider that it is possible to order strings and DateTimes, too.

Comment: it does not accept year month and day and also tostring.

Comment: @Nakres Which type does your DateTime has?

Comment: @Nakres are you really talking about this [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: value was missing Convert.ToDecimal(dt.value.ToString("yyyyMMdd")); worked

Comment: @Nakres ok I updated my code. Please mark your favorite answer as somution so this topic can be closed

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ToBinary()`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi3qZ3xnYXQAhXBxVQKHVaFDGkQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.datetime.tobinary(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNFU-RBiT6HTfdNJWhjdtMBodGP7lQ) to get a binary representation of the `DateTime` - this can, then, be assigned to a `decimal`.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
decimal dec = dt.ToBinary ();
```

This is the most straightforward conversion that doesn't involve converting to a string and back. If you're using a nullable date/time, just use the `Value` property to get the actual value out of it (with error checking, etc.)