# SQL Server - Error converting data type float to bigint

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

Can the datatype of a field be changed to bigint from float ??

Create a new column that's an integer:

```
ALTER TABLE tabl ADD newCol int;
```

Select the data from the old column into the new one:

```
UPDATE tabl SET newCol = CAST(TEL2 AS int) FROM tabl ;
```

P.S: I am using MS SQL Server

i try to us this in c# but it didn't get any result

```
  string sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM tabl WHERE CONCAT([TEL1], [TEL2],[TEL3], [TEL4],[TEL5], [TEL6],[TEL7], [TEL8],[TEL9]) LIKE '%" + txtBoxSearch.Text + "%'";
```

**I store telephone numbers as float and try find it by the c# code and didn't get any result so im trying to convert the column or correct the c# code**

Comment: It is not clear where is your problem. Where are the FLOAT and BIGINT in your table? What has to do the final query with your problem? Do you store telephone numbers as float?

Comment: i update it now

Comment: See here why your choice to store tel numbers as float is wrong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483156/whats-the-right-way-to-represent-phone-numbers

Comment: If you are able to change the table then make phone numbers varchar instead of numeric.

Comment: @Crowcoder it is FLOAT and i can't convert it

Comment: @ahmed then I am confused by the statements about converting them to bigint.

Comment: @Steve i have now more then 1000000 recode what should i do

Comment: @Crowcoder i need to convert it to any thing to us it bout i can't

Comment: Add another column, convert the floats to strings and then check what happened in the converted column. Perhaps you can recover something. But sooner or later you need to fix this error.

Comment: why can't you change that?

Comment: @tylkonachwile i try everything in google and stack overflow and i didn't find any thing

Comment: Use this in your SQL string to convert your float to varchar: `SELECT STR(float_field, 25, 0)`. For more information, refer to STR() function document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @RahulSharma ok it good bout it make a new column not convert it

Comment: What do you mean by that? I am not quite sure what is your problem here?

Comment: @RahulSharma it work in sql server bout it not working in my c# code

Comment: @RahulSharma thx for your help alout

Comment: @RahulSharma yes i get what i want :) thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [STR()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) function:

```
SELECT STR(your_float_field, 25, 0)
```

This would return your float value as a string.
Note: This function pads on the left with spaces. If this is a problem, combine with LTRIM function:

```
SELECT LTRIM(STR(your_float_field, 25, 0))
```

Answer (score -1):

No,because float contain decimals 
And bigint contain only integer.
But bigint can be converted into 
Float as float contain both part -integer and decimals.
If your float value contains .00 as the decimal value then it can be changed into bigint.
Thanks.
If you want more about datatype conversion.then please comment.
Thanks again.

Comment: Are you understanding the above answer.

Comment: yes i understand  that .  now it is a number (21412124) when i convert it to nvarchar it be like (2.1412e+)

Comment: This is because mysql convert the no. According to it's unicode character.