# Integer or String for a phone number?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I want to know if I have to use a string or an integer for a phone number?

I have tried an `integer` but I have a problem in my validation.

`...
table->integer('phone');
...`

In my validation, I must have between 8 and 11 characters.

I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

`'phone' => 'required|numeric|between:8,11',`

I think the `string` is better?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the right way to represent phone numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483156/whats-the-right-way-to-represent-phone-numbers) (yes, that's a Java question, but the answer is the same: phone numbers are *always* strings)

Comment: It's better if you read here before making any assumption on phone numbers: https://github.com/jameslk/awesome-falsehoods and here: https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md So, IMHO, use a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the validation should be like this

```
'phone' => 'required|numeric|min:8|max:11',
```

Answer (score 9):

**“I want to know if I have to use a string or an integer for a phone number”**

If you want to do some calculations with the `numbers` which you going to be storing (inserting), then you have to use `int`(in Laravel migration: it is `integer`) or any other data type such as `double` etc. (as per your requirement to do such operations) as the data type of the `field`.

However If you do not want to do some calculations with it, then use the data type as `varchar` (in Laravel migration: it is `string`) as the data type of the field.

So, when it comes to storing `Phone numbers`, you can use the
`varchar` data type as you do not have to do calculations with Phone
numbers.

So in this case, your validation should be this:

```
'phone' => 'required|string|min:8|max:11'
```

Comment: +1 for this because in the future you may need to add the "+" symbol in your phone numbers or a "-" or another character.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
'phone' => ' required|digits:10'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
'phone' => 'required|min:8|max:11|regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/',
```