# Sails Js "contains" does not accept numberr

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I am trying to execute the query below is my query

```
Product.find({mobile:{contains:998888}})
```

I am getting error below

> Could not use the provided `where` clause.  Could not filter by `mobile`: A `contains` (i.e. string search) modifier cannot be used with a boolean or numeric attribute (it wouldn't make any sense).

I want to search number in a column which is the data type is "int". I am using MYSQL for database.

Comment: Do a numeric comparison instead?

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/find

Comment: I'd strongly suggest against storing a phone number in the database as an integer - [some reasoning as to why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3483166/742129).. Here in Australia a mobile number starts with `04...`. If storing this as an integer you lose the leading 0 and it's not a valid phone number. If you store the phone number as a string (even if it only contains numeric characters) you can do your "contains" style queries, and MySQL won't screw up your input.

Comment: It is just an example. I want to search by number. Number search is faster than string search.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the `in` operator. I doubt there's going to be any way to do substring matching on non-string values within the ORM.

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/query-language#?in