# Why is my switch case which is inside a do while loop not working and breaks out of the loop even when it should continue?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, do-while

Expected behavior is to take the name as input and run the while loop again but instead it just goes to the next line and does nothing.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;   
int main()
{
    int ch,mb;
    bool y=true;
    char name;
    cout<<"Enter 1,2 or 3 : ";
    do{
             cin>>ch;
             switch(ch)
             {
                 case 1:
                     cout<<" \n\t 1.ENTER CUSTOMER NAME :";    
                     cin>>name;     
                     continue;
                 case 2:
                     cout<<" \n\t 2.ENTER MOBILE NUMBER:";
                     cin>>mb;
                     continue;
                 case 3:
                     y=false;
            }
      }while(y!=false);
}
```

Comment: I think you need break and not continue there.

Comment: Move `cout<<"Enter 1,2 or 3 : ";` to inside the loop?

Comment: "*but instead it just goes to the next line and does nothing.*" what does this mean? What does going to the next line mean? What does doing nothing mean? What (exactly) do you expect to see, and what (exactly) are you actually seeing?

Comment: Also, `char name;` That should be a `char []` or even better, `std::string`. I am assuming `name` is more than one character.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: In addition if OP try to type more characters, next character would go for `std::cin >> ch;` so infinite failed parsing...

Comment: @Delta_G They would do the same thing.

Comment: @Jarod42 Misread, thank you.

Comment: OK.  I've never seen an example of continue used in a switch.  I see now that it is continuing the do-while and not working on the switch at all.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, there are definitely issues with the input code. `name` could have spaces. Phone numbers often have dashes `-` (in the US anyway). OP should look into `std::getline()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't "do nothing"; it waits for the next input. Because that's what you told it to do!

If you want to get another prompt, move the `cout<<"Enter 1,2 or 3 : ";` line *inside* the loop.

---

By the way, a `char` is *one byte* so that's not really appropriate for reading a whole customer name; furthermore, [you should avoid using `int`s for telephone numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3483156/4386278).

Comment: yes, I have changed it to double and it's working great now. And the code is working well now.

Comment: Changing the phone number to `double` is going in the wrong direction. Please click on the link I provided and _read_ the information.

Comment: Thank you, I have changed it to string now. I mean I did encounter some issues while testing with int, double by including large numbers, I get it now that string solves the problem entirely. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: No problem. By the way, you accepted an incorrect & incomplete answer.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Incomplete answer?

Comment: Yes the other answer is missing all the tips I gave you, as well as containing a false statement regarding `break`/`continue`. Not sure why you preferred it. :(

Comment: You can't "tick both". https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thank you for helping out a newbie.

Comment: You got it sairahulare!

Answer (score 0):

Use break; instead of continue;
break will move execution to the end of the switch.

Edit: I think the issue is that you are just not seeing your prompt again. so move it inside your loop.

Comment: In this case `continue` should work as well as a `break`.

Comment: `continue` should just check the loop conditional and re-execute it. In this case, while break is the correct, I don't think it's causing OP's error.

Comment: _"break will move execution to the end of the switch"_ which contains nothing, so the loop will begin anew.... just as if you'd written `continue`.....